# Wordpress updated to 6.0.2 doesn't show the home page content in laptop but shows the content in mobile

Tags: php, wordpress

The website is accesnaturelaurentides.com
You can open the website and see the problem. I turned off every plugin and turned it on one by one. However, that didn't solve the problem. I turned on wp_debug and found some construct problem and solved them but that also didn't solve the problem. I downgraded the Wordpress version but that also didn't solve the problem. I am out of ideas.

Comment: External links change and break over time, which removes all future value for visitors to this question. Update your question to include a [mre] of the problem you’re describing in accordance with [ask].

Comment: I am sorry for this, the theme is heavily customized. So I don't even know where the error was coming from or to what to include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://prnt.sc/kAh1bcjkrNGB

please check css .thb-desktop .thb-section-row

it has opacity 0 please remove it, and your content will show

Comment: Thank you so much. Didn't think css would be a problem and didn't search for it. It solved my problem.

Comment: great to hear :)